# How I join two tables in such a way that the content in first table displays first

Tags: mysql

I have two database tables (zporeport,statusfile), I want to fetch the zporeport column in statusfile.

My statusfile database table.

```
CREATE TABLE `statusfile` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `new_sap_po` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `lino_no` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `materialno` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `material` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `qty` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `incoterm` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `remark_for_delay` varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

My zporeport database table.

```
CREATE TABLE `zporeport` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `materialno` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `material` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `purchasing_document` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ab_available_date` date NOT NULL,
  `order_quantity` varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

I want to get the ab_available_date from zporeport and get into statusfile.

Here my nodejs sql query code.

```
 const qr = `
    SELECT statusfile.material, statusfile.materialno, statusfile.qty, statusfile.remark_for_delay, zporeport.ab_available_date 
    FROM statusfile 
    INNER JOIN zporeport ON statusfile.material
    limit 10;
  `;
```

The query doesn't give me the zporeport ab_available_date.
Please correct my query to get the zporert ab_available_date in statusfile.

Comment: Did you try joining on `materialno` ? Though it don't have to do anything with date.



Can you change the join condition to this and let us know any difference in output

`INNER JOIN zporeport ON statusfile.materialno = zporeport.materialno`

Comment: I will try that but not giving any output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sf.id, sf.new_sap_po, sf.lino_no, sf.materialno, sf.material, sf.qty, sf.incoterm, sf.remark_for_delay, zr.ab_available_date
FROM statusfile sf
JOIN zporeport zr
ON sf.id = zr.id AND sf.materialno = zr.materialno;
```

This query will select all columns from statusfile and the ab_available_date column from zporeport, where the id and materialno columns match between the two tables.

Comment: the query not giving any output in postman.

Comment: for this query to work you need to have record which satisfies the condition sf.id == zr.id and sf.materialno == zr.materialno.